# Reading comma and space separated numbers from a text file

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a text file which contains numbers that are separated with comma and also space. It is in fact a file that in each row contains the index of row and pairs of numbers, such that the pairs are separated with space and the numbers of each pair is separated with comma. The number of columns in each row is different. 
For example two rows of the file are as below:

```
1 34,10 12,23
2 22,123 11,102 12,34 22,232
```

I tried `dlmread` but it gives error, as there are commas in the file. I tried `csvread` but it reads just some of the data and in an unclear pattern. I also used:

`mymatrix = load('filename.txt','-ascii')`

but it gives error because the number of columns are not the same in each row.

How can I read this irregular data pattern?

Comment: have you tried `importdata`? Try the Importdata-Gui as well.

Comment: I just tried it, but it reads each row as a string, so the output is a matrix where each row of matrix is a string containing each row of the file.

Comment: if every row has a different length, then this is still the best option. Now you need to loop `textscan` or `regexp` over it, to get your numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**`importdata`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) GUI is a really mighty tool:

[image]

I almost never encountered a case where it wouldn't work. Sometimes it's overkill because the structure of the file is more regular and other functions should be used. But in your case with different row lenghts it is a good option.

The nice thing is, it's intuitive: input your file, change some parameters and finally **generate a script automatically** ("Import Selection Button"):

[image]

And you get a nice double matrix:

```
data =

     1    34    10    12    23   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
     2    22   123    11   102    12    34    22   232
```

---

If you have multiple files with a different maximum number of value pairs per row, you either could use the file where occurs the overall maximum number or you take the generated script and modify it for dynamic detection. But first see, if this already works well enough for you.

---

This is the code generated by the GUI:

```
filename = 'data.txt';

formatSpec = '%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%[^\n\r]';
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
data = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', {',',' '}, ...
               'MultipleDelimsAsOne', true, 'EmptyValue' ,NaN, 'ReturnOnError', false);
out = [data{1:end-1}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the general case in which you do not know in advance the maximum number of data in the input file, you can read the file row by row by using `fgetl`.

`fgetl` returns a `char` string that you can then convert to an `array` of number by using `str2num`

Since each array might have different length, you can then assign the array to a `cellarray` in which to collect all the data.

```
% Open input file
fid=fopen('tmp_in.txt');
% Initialize output
the_data=[];
% Read the input file
while 1
   tline = fgetl(fid);
   if(~ischar(tline))
      break
   end
% Convert to number and store in a cellarray
   the_data=cat(1,the_data,{str2num(tline)})
end
% Close the input file
fclose(fid);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the method of the first answer and it worked; later, after I finish the homework, I may try your method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since the row lengths are irregular I don't believe there's a simple solution. But here's a strategy that should work.

1. Iterate over each line in the file. `fgetl` will work.
2. For each line, 
          do `nPair = length(strfind(myLine, ','));`
3. `formatSpec = ['%d', repmat(' %d,%d', [nPair, 1])]`
4. `rowNums = textscan(myLine, formatSpec);`
5. `rowNums` now has the numbers of the line as a cell array.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I tried the method of the first answer and it worked; later, after I finish the homework, I may try your method as well.